# Unable to display dictionary object value in label

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm displaying an array of dictionaries that comes from web service, in a table. This is the code snippet in cellForRowAtIndexPath.

```
cell.businessNameLabel.text = [dataDict objectForKey:@"business_name"];
[cell.businessNameLabel setTextColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:1.0/255.0 green:135.0/255.0 blue:68.0/255.0 alpha:1]];
UIFont *customfont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"MyriadPro-Bold" size:16];
[cell.businessNameLabel setFont:customfont];

cell.serviceTypeLabel.text = [dataDict objectForKey:@"address"];
[cell.serviceTypeLabel setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
customfont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"MyriadPro-Regular" size:11];
[cell.serviceTypeLabel setFont:customfont];

cell.businessID = [dataDict objectForKey:@"business_id"];
cell.reviewScoreLabel.text = [dataDict objectForKey:@"rating"];

return cell;
```

The app crashes on the following line:

```
cell.reviewScoreLabel.text = [dataDict objectForKey:@"rating"];
```

With the following exception detail:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFNumber rangeOfCharacterFromSet:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xb000000000000003'
```

The dictionary object data looks something like this:

```
address = "Boston, MA, United States";
"business_id" = 15;
"business_image" = "http://demo.web.com/home-business/upload/user/1420452418_.jpeg";
"business_name" = autodealersma;
lat = "42.3584865";
lng = "-71.06009699999998";
rating = "4.3";    
service = "auto dealers";
```

Comment: The "4.3" seems to be a `NSNumber` and not a `NSString`.

Comment: I think it is because you are trying to set an NSNumber to a text property. The text property needs a NSString. Could you try: `cell.reviewScoreLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[dataDict objectForKey:@"rating"]];` Please see my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is because you are trying to set an NSNumber to a text property. The text property needs a NSString. Could you try:

`cell.reviewScoreLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[dataDict objectForKey:@"rating"]];`

Answer (score 0):

try this ...

```
cell.businessNameLabel.text = [[dataDict objectForKey:@"business_name"]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
[cell.businessNameLabel setTextColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:1.0/255.0 green:135.0/255.0 blue:68.0/255.0 alpha:1]];
UIFont *customfont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"MyriadPro-Bold" size:16];
[cell.businessNameLabel setFont:customfont];

cell.serviceTypeLabel.text = [[dataDict objectForKey:@"address"]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
[cell.serviceTypeLabel setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
customfont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"MyriadPro-Regular" size:11];
[cell.serviceTypeLabel setFont:customfont];

cell.businessID = [[dataDict objectForKey:@"business_id"]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.reviewScoreLabel.text = [[dataDict objectForKey:@"rating"]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

return cell;
```

Comment: check now i have edited answer

Comment: now it crashes. I think typecasting IS the solution

Answer (score 0):

Modify your code to

```
cell.businessNameLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [dataDict objectForKey:@"business_name"]];
[cell.businessNameLabel setTextColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:1.0/255.0 green:135.0/255.0 blue:68.0/255.0 alpha:1]];
UIFont *customfont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"MyriadPro-Bold" size:16];
[cell.businessNameLabel setFont:customfont];

cell.serviceTypeLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[dataDict objectForKey:@"address"]];
[cell.serviceTypeLabel setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
customfont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"MyriadPro-Regular" size:11];
[cell.serviceTypeLabel setFont:customfont];

cell.businessID = [dataDict objectForKey:@"business_id"];
cell.reviewScoreLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[dataDict objectForKey:@"rating"]];

return cell;
```

The reason of the crash must be this, the `object` you are trying to set to your label may not be a `NSString`. So better take `StringValue` or format it.